# Increase font size in input field

Tags: html, css, input, font-size

I have a large input field and I can't figure out how to make the text larger without making the input field even bigger. When I set the font size to 2em, for example, the input field grows to take up the whole page. Tried fixing it with `line-height` and that didn't work. Any suggestions? Thanks. I included a pic of the current size, and I'd like the text to fill the field.

current situation
[image]

HTML:

```
<table class="contact-table">
            <tr id="test">
                <td id="contact-image">
                    <img id="library" src="library.jpeg"/>
                </td>
                <td id="contact-form">
                    <div class="label-wrapper">
                        <label for="name">Name</label>
                        <input id="name" type="text" name="name" class="top-input">
                    </div>
                    <div class="label-wrapper">
                        <label for="email">Email Address</label>
                        <input id="email" type="text" name="email" class="top-input">
                    </div>
                    <div class="label-wrapper">
                        <label for="message">Message</label>
                        <textarea id="message" type="text" name="message"></textarea>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

CSS:

```css
.contact-table {
    width: 100%;
}

#contact-form {
    width: 50%;
    padding-right: 8%;
}

.label-wrapper {
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 2em;
}

.top-input {
    width: 30em;
    height: 4em;
    border-radius: 5px;
    display: inline-block;
    border: white;
    line-height: inherit;
    font-size:
}

#message {
    width: 61em;
    height: 30em;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: white;
}
```

Comment: Would be better if you show some code or a fiddle where it's reproducable.

Comment: added in my html and css. thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this by using `rem` (or another method, like pixel size) to dictate the height of the input field.  For example, this snippet sets the input text size to `2em` but keeps the input box "normal size" by setting the height to `1rem`.

```css
body {
  font-size: 1em;
}

#inputField {
  font-size: 2em;
  height: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<p>Normal Text</p>
<input id="inputField" />
```

Comment: Worked great. Thanks for the suggestion and explanation.